# Magento 1.7: I can't stop reindex process

Tags: magento-1.7, reindex

I'm trying to separate magento back end and front end in 2 nodes. I follow the HOW-TO on magento site. Now I have two installation of magento that work properly. My problem comes when  magento start reindex process. It doesn't stop, it's in pending state since friday (5 days). 
I try to stop it by removing all locks file in /var/locks folder and restarting apache, but nothing has changed. Now I can't restart it because magento throw me an exception because reindex is in progress and I can't install any extension.

How can I restore the state of reindex process?

Comment: Make sure you are removing the items from the `var/locks` folder under your magento instance. I do not think it should have the first `/`

Comment: @DavidManners. Please put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `var/locks` folder you are clearing is under your Magento root dir and not simply your base linux var folder.